# Mixing C and Assembly xcode - constants

Tags: ios, c, xcode, assembly

I'm having some problems mixing C and Assembly when it comes to dealing with constants. I'm using XCode 6.1.

For instance, I have this assembly file:

```
    .section __DATA,__data,regular
    .globl  _memLoc
    .globl  _myData

    _myData = 0x01234567  // <--- my constant

    .align  2

_memLoc:

    .long _myData
```

Here I'm generating a 4 byte value which is stored in a memory location labelled _memLoc. I can reference this memory location from C just fine:

```
extern uint32_t memLoc;
uint32_t *ptr = &memLoc;
```

Inspecting *ptr yields the expected result. Now I would also like to reference _myData from C, but I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I've tried this with no luck:

```
extern uint32_t myData;
uint32_t value = myData;
```

What's the actual difference between _memLoc and _myData? Both symbols are created and made global at assembly time yet the reference to _myData causes the program to fail.

What I'm actually trying to do here is to define a constant just once and make it accessible from both C and Assembly. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Have you tried with `_myData` from your C code?

Comment: @Michael Makes no difference - the leading underscore is added to the symbol by the C compiler. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simpler than I would have imagined. The assembler does recognize preprocessor directives so all I had to do was put my constants in a regular .h file and import it in the .s file:

```
#include "Myconstants.h"
...
_memLoc:
    .long MYCONSTANT
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709850/conditional-compilation-in-assembler-s-code-for-iphone-how) set me off on the right track.